# XAMPP, не запускается MySQL

Tags: mysql

При запуске MySQL в XAMMP происходит следующее:

```
22:43:48  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
22:43:49  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
22:43:58  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
22:43:58  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
22:43:58  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:43:58  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
22:43:58  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:43:58  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:43:58  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
22:43:58  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Лог mysql_error:

```
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 113863; transaction id 9
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-04 22:43:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200104 22:43:50
2020-01-04 22:43:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Из-за чего это появляется и как это исправить? Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
22:43:58  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies
```

Возможно у вас закрыт порт (скорее всего 3308), гуглите как открыть порты

*Самый простой способ - полностью отключить брандмауэр и сетевую защиту, но я не рекомендую так делать, если будете использовать как реальный сервер свой компьютер*

Comment: Зачем брандмауэр? Проще в конфигах мускула поменять на открытый  порт )